# Not able to attach auth token from cache in hosted services

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm new to .net and I really want to understand this behavior of an application. I have a function called `GetOrg()` which basically requests the API endpoint and grabs the data, to get the data I need to pass Auth token with every request. To get Auth token I have another function call `GetAccessToken` gets the token and save it in the cache. I have created an named `httpclient` which attaches the token to every request for  `NonProductionEnv` client.

Now the problem is when I setup `GetOrg()` in hosted services as shown below its not attaching the token and request API endpoint without auth token but if I setup `GetOrg()` in controller it works just fine.

Hosted Service:

```
public class TokenService : DelegatingHandler, IHostedService
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    protected IMemoryCache _cache;
    private Timer _timer;
    public IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
    protected HttpClient _client_NP;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public TokenService(IConfiguration configuration, IMemoryCache memoryCache, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _cache = memoryCache;
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;

        // NamedClients foreach Env.
        _client_NP = _clientFactory.CreateClient("NonProductionEnv");
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(GetAccessToken, null, 0, 3300000);
        // Thread.Sleep(2000);
        _timer = new Timer(Heartbeat, null, 1000, 1000);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Timer does not have a stop. 
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task<Token> GetToken(Uri authenticationUrl, Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(authenticationCredentials);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(authenticationUrl, content);

        if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string message = String.Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
            throw new ApplicationException(message);
        }

        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Token token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(responseString);

        return token;
    }

    private void GetAccessToken(object state)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials_np = Configuration.GetSection("NonProductionEnvironment:Credentials").GetChildren().Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        Token token_np = GetToken(new Uri(Configuration["NonProductionEnvironment:URL"]), authenticationCredentials_np).Result;

        _cache.Set("np", token_np.AccessToken);
    }

    public void Heartbeat(object state)
    {
        // Discard the result
        _ = GetOrg();
    }

    public async Task GetOrg()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "organizations");
        var response = await _client_NP.SendAsync(request);
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        OrganizationsClass.OrgsRootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrganizationsClass.OrgsRootObject>(json);

        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PCFStatusContext>();

            foreach (var item in model.resources)
            {
                var g = Guid.Parse(item.guid);
                var x = _DBcontext.Organizations.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrgGuid == g);
                if (x == null)
                {
                    _DBcontext.Organizations.Add(new Organizations
                    {
                        OrgGuid = g,
                        Name = item.name,
                        CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                        UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                        Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                        Foundation = 3
                    });
                }
                else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at)
                {
                    x.CreatedAt = item.created_at;
                    x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                    x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }

            await GetSpace();
            await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

}
```

Named Client in Startup:

```
    services.AddHttpClient("NonProductionEnv", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["NonProductionEnvironment:NP_API_URL"]);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", (String)_cache.Get("np"));
});
```

The below log in generating every second as I need to call api endpoint every second.

> Now listening on: https://localhost:5001 Now listening on:
>   http://localhost:5000 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
>   info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.NonProductionEnv.LogicalHandler[100]
>         Start processing HTTP request GET https://api.sample.io/v3/organizations info:
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.NonProductionEnv.ClientHandler[100]
>         Sending HTTP request GET https://api.sample.io/v3/organizations info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.NonProductionEnv.ClientHandler[101]
>         Received HTTP response after 53.3973ms - Unauthorized

PS: I don't know much about .net and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `HttpClient` is being registered with a static value being retrieved from cache *at app startup*. At this point, your hosted service has not yet run, so there is no value in cache yet. Once there finally is a value in cache, the header has already long since been set, and you never reset it.

Cache is actually entirely unnecessary here. You also don't need to set the `Authorization` header in the actual client registration. Instead, just simply modify your `GetAccessToken` method to:

```
private void GetAccessToken(object state)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials_np = Configuration.GetSection("NonProductionEnvironment:Credentials").GetChildren().Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    Token token_np = GetToken(new Uri(Configuration["NonProductionEnvironment:URL"]), authenticationCredentials_np).Result;

    _client_NP.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token_np.AccessToken}");
}
```

Comment: DefaultHeaders was giving me an error `'HttpClient' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultHeaders' and no accessible extension method 'DefaultHeaders' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` so I replaced it with `DefaultRequestHeaders` and the it gave me `Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Cannot add value because header 'Authorization' does not support multiple values.`

Comment: Sorry, it's `DefaultRequestHeaders`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: program runs but the behavior is weird sometime it attaches the token and sometimes not what could be the problem?